# Java JSON Parser with Regex

Tags: java, json, regex

I have JSON response from server. JSON has exception info inside of it.
I need to parse it to detect that exception occurred and identify which one.

JSON  example:

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to what I need

```
Pattern errorCodePattern = Pattern.compile("\"code\"\\s*:\\s*\"([^,]*)\",");
Pattern messagePattern = Pattern.compile("\"message\"\\s*:\\s*\"([^,]*)\",");
Pattern statusPattern = Pattern.compile("\"status\"\\s*:\\s*\"(FAILURE)\"");
 Matcher errorCodeMatcher = errorCodePattern.matcher(response);
Matcher messageMatcher = messagePattern.matcher(response);
Matcher statusMatcher = statusPattern.matcher(response);
```

[Java JSON Parser Example with Regex](http://www.codearsenal.net/2016/02/java-json-parser-example-regex.html)